# what's wrong with my ufw configuration on Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server, ufw

I've setup the ufw firewall for my Ubuntu server on linode as follows:

[image: Lish terminal info]

Note that this is in the Lish terminal, unfortunately as soon as I turn on the ufw, I cannot:

- view my test website via port 80 from browser, or even curl -I to get its response headers;
- I cannot ssh to the server, even port 22 is "allowing access";

The default action for ufw is denying, which I believe is good practice for a "defensive" firewall. I am new to system admin stuff so I am not very sure which part I've done wrong...

Any thoughts?

**UPDATED as suggested:**
Here are the print outs from iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Tue Dec 14 09:55:24 2010
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [80376:49275670]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [39230:5028423]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec 14 09:55:24 2010
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Tue Dec 14 09:55:24 2010
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [81286:49365430]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [39230:5028423]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec 14 09:55:24 2010
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Tue Dec 14 09:55:24 2010
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1419:87729]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2334:168647]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2334:168647]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec 14 09:55:24 2010
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Tue Dec 14 09:55:24 2010
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [81286:49365430]
:INPUT ACCEPT [81274:49361314]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [39230:5028423]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [39230:5028423]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec 14 09:55:24 2010
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Tue Dec 14 09:55:24 2010
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [713:54735]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [666:62866]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input 
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input 
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input 
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input 
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input 
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input 
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input 
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] " 
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward 
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-input -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-input -m state --state INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny 
-A ufw-before-input -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local 
-A ufw-before-input -s 224.0.0.0/4 -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input 
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-output -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output 
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] " 
-A ufw-logging-deny -m state --state INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN 
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] " 
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN 
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN 
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN 
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny 
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP 
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP 
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-track-input -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-track-input -p udp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23 -j DROP 
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] " 
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec 14 09:55:24 2010
```

Comment: Could you run `sudo iptables-save` in Lish, and then update your question with its output?

Comment: @Steven Monai: updated the output. To be frank I am not very fond of the "not-so-human-readable" iptables so I chose ufw in the hope that it would help me setup firewall... but it seems not configured right at the moment.

Comment: Looking at your `iptables-save`, it does not seem like any traffic would be blocked by that configuration: All built-in chain policies are to ACCEPT (except FORWARD chain on filter table, but that's irrelevant on a box that's not a router), none of the user-defined chains are referenced anywhere, and there are no DROP or REJECT targets anywhere. Sorry, I am at a loss to explain why your web and ssh requests would be blocked by this.

Comment: @Steven Monai: you should have made your comment as an answer so I can get you the tick :)

Comment: Taking a closer look at your `iptables-save`, it seems I spoke a little hastily. There are a few DROP targets in there. However, there is no way that any of them would be reached, as they are all in user-defined chains that are not referenced. And, please, I implore you: don't assign a tick to an "answer" that doesn't solve your question! Someone out there might have the true solution, and you don't want to discourage them from posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would seriously consider using something like the the iptables firewall generator to make your rules, I spend two days trying to use iptables as a router and after using this site i got it working in 5 mins.

Heres the link: http://easyfwgen.morizot.net/gen/

Hope that helps,
RayQuang

Answer (score 2):

I dump ufw and use Shorewall instead.  It is installable as a package.  The /usr/share/doc/shorewall/examples directory has good starting configurations.  It is will documented both on the  [Shoreline Firewall site](http://shorewall.net/) and in the shorewall-doc packagage.

Answer (score 1):

May be your iptables-save is incomplete here?

If you run iptables-save - it dumps current rules. To make actual ufw rules current - you should run after configuring ufw:

```
# ufw enable
# /lib/ufw/ufw-init restart
```

Mine rules indeed contained a chain, that preventd all input traffic to pass:

```
*filter
...
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
...
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
...
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
```

which dropped all input traffic:
input => ufw-before-input => ufw-not-local => DROP

i managed to fix that by modifying /etc/ufw/before.rules:
comennt out this line

```
 -A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
```